# Ubuntu 12.04 / Elementary OS - Shutdown Problem / Logfiles

Tags: shutdown

I have new Desktop PC on which I've installed Elementary OS, based on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

The problem: the system doesn't shut down as expected: When using the 'Shut Down' option from the main menu,
or typing
    $ sudo shutdown -P now
in a terminal window, the screen turns black immediately, but the PC doesn't power off.

*** I know, this was asked before, but none of the tips work for me.

I've tested all(?) the grub options, found here and in other sites but to no avail.

This happens every time, no matter if additional user programs are running, or the shutdown attempt was made immediately after startup.

Basic system info:

- Intel Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4130 CPU @ 3.40GHz
- no extra graphics adapter, using the built in
- SSD drive: Crucial M500 120GB  (the boot drive)
- a 2 GB Toshiba FDD is present, but not yet formatted.
- Fritz USB WLAN stick - using ndiswrapper

Trying to pinpoint the root cause, I was looking in the /var/log directory for any helpfull log entry, but there is nothing in it:

/var/log/syslog:

```
Mar  6 17:45:55 ludmilla kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Mar  6 17:45:55 ludmilla rsyslogd: [originMar  6 17:48:23 ludmilla kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
```

that's it

manually switched off, then - after a some minutes I started it again; these are the first lines after startup:

```
Mar  6 17:48:23 ludmilla rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="644" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Mar  6 17:48:23 ludmilla rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103
Mar  6 17:48:23 ludmilla rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
Mar  6 17:48:23 ludmilla rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole' [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
```

same in /var/log/kern.log:

```
Mar  6 17:45:55 ludmilla kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.

...

Mar  6 17:48:23 ludmilla kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Mar  6 17:48:23 ludmilla kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Mar  6 17:48:23 ludmilla kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
```

The only reliable way to power it off without using the hardware button is to issue:

```
# poweroff -fp
```

But I doubt that this is good practice. (this is bypassing the shutdown procedure)

My questions are:

1. does anyone has a solution for this problem?
2. Or any more tips what the cause might be?
3. Any information if there are more logs in which I may find the root cause?
4. Is there a "shutdown debug mode" for generating the missing information? - to see every step while the shutdown is executed?
5. poweroff -fp: can this do any harm to the system?